# Optimizing Canvas animation in Opera browser

Tags: html, canvas

I have tried to use : http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/drawing-trees-in-canvas/

for some testing and found that on Opera12 browser, lot of CPU is consumed. Please let me know if there is any way by which we can reduce and optimize CPU utilization?

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: I have to wonder if there isn't something with your settings or your video card that's causing the issue.  I'm not seeing any difference (or frankly any spikes whatsoever) between chrome and opera.